# I can not see geometry column on SQL Executor of FME

Tags: fme-form

I have build a simple workflow in FME 2014 (as shown in the image) to get data from an excel file and store them in a postgres database. For this purpose I use SQL Executor.
I manage to pass all the data to the database but for some reason I can not see in the dialog box where I build the SQL Statement (in the properties of SQL Executor) the geom column which I have in my database table.
Why this happens?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because you're using the Postgres format, which FME would class as non-spatial (or tabular). If you used PostGIS instead it might show you the geometry column.

Regardless, I agree with the other poster that the more usual approach would be to use a Writer, rather than trying to pass data through the SQLExecutor. Then geometry is handled automatically.

If you're new to FME, then please do feel free to contact the support team (http://safe.com/support) and ask for their assistance or guidance. Not that I'm against posting on this site, I just figure you might get quicker answers.

Comment: I tried to change the format from PostgreSQL to PostGIS but unfortunately it doesn't work either. Its quite strange that neglects the geometry column of my table. I also found out that in order to show the "user attribute" geometry (which comes from the excel file that I have) I need to use a transformer called "Geometry Extractor". But still this doesn't solve the problem with the missing geometry column. I will try the other approach you mention with the Writer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's point data (X Y Coordinates) in your Excel file, you could use the 2DPointReplacer 'Transformer' to create the point geometry, choosing your x and y coordinates accordingly.

It may then easier to use a PostGIS 'Writer' to insert the data into the database and let FME take care of the spatial table creation.

Comment: The coordinates are not stored inside the Excel but I want to take them from a shape file. Also this is not a one time insert of data but the database will be updated with new data regularly (new rows). So I need to have the structure defined in postgis. I still don't understand why the geometry column doesn't appear in the SQL Executor. Seems like that this datatype is not recognizable.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are looking a way to handle geometry field as you can see through Postgres-Postgis. Transformer Geometry Extractor will create a field with the geometry encoding you desire.